# Twilio Video Call Disconnected Automatically after 1 minute

Tags: ios, twilio, videochat

I have implement Twilio Video chat one of my iOS application, when 2 persons are making a video call with each other it has been observed after 1 minute and 28 second video call is disconnected automatically even though there is no internet issue. We have already upgraded twilio account, but the issue is still persistent.

One another issue is can you please help us how to Allow voice chat to be on earphone and not just speaker phone currently whenever we are using the video call it by defaults on speaker phone.

Comment: I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to report the disconnection issue and they will be able to help you debug that. I am finding out about your speaker question though. I've found [this](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.0-beta6/docs/Constants/TVIAudioOutput.html) so far, but not sure it's quite right.

Comment: philnash Thank you